# Selecting form field on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I'm trying to prepare my first Greasmonkey script (with no experience in javascript/websites technologies) and I have problem with selecting field on a page. It is:

`<input data-testid="user/fullName" autocomplete="name" class="form-control u-text-normal">`

I've tested:

1. `document.querySelectorAll("input.form-control");`
2. `document.querySelectorAll("input.form-control.u-text-normal");`
3. `document.getElementById("user/fullName").value`

but non of them is returning what I need... and what I need is possibility to fill that form field with the script. Could you help, please?

EDIT:
The methods given in the following answers I try to run in the browser console and they do not return me any element. Maybe someone could try to run it and tell me what I'm doing wrong? The website is a shopping cart on the [pizza site](http://www.bravo.wroclaw.pl/grunwald.html) :) But to see it you need to add pizza to cart ("Do koszyka") for a minimum of 20 zł and then go to payment ("Do kasy"). Then the first field "Imie i nazwisko" is what I would like to fill at the beginning.

Comment: What do you get when you use these selectors? Do you get other fields, too many fields, or no fields?

Comment: Also when are you calling them? If they are executed before they exist (eg your script comes before the elements in the html) you wouldnt be able to get a reference. Also provide a [mcve] we can only make guesses with just a couple of lines of code to go on

Comment: Forgot to write it. I get no fields.

Comment: You may need to wait for the page finish loading. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   console.log('document is ready. I can sleep now');
});`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a single element, give the html element an id example:

```
<html>
<input id='id_here'data-testid="user/fullName" autocomplete="name" class="form-control u-text-normal">
</html>
```

then get the element using

```
document.getElementById('id_here');
```

For multiple elements that share the same class you could use the query selector

```
document.querySelector('.form-control')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```js
var example = document.querySelector('.form-control').value;
document.write(example);
```

```html
<input data-testid="user/fullName" autocomplete="name" class="form-control u-text-normal" value="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to select this element, use the most specific thing, in this case `data-testid`:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='user/fullName']")
console.log(x[0].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

to select the element (here we select with the class and the data property to be the most accurate) =>

```
var element = document.querySelector('.form-control[data-testid="user/fullName"]');
```

After if you want add some value in this input =>

```
element.value = "My_value";
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can add 'id' or select your field by querySelector

```js
let input = document.querySelector('[data-testid="user/fullName"]')

input.value='abc';

myField.value += '123';
```

```html
<input id="myField" data-testid="user/fullName" autocomplete="name" class="form-control u-text-normal">
```

**Update**

I try my method and it works [pizza](http://www.bravo.wroclaw.pl/grunwald.html) site which you mention in your question update:

[image]

But it looks like that console 'see' dom input element after you find it using `right click> inspect element` - strange